# Cannot locate Error in eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project that has a red x in explorer at the project level.

None of the source files have an error or a red x it only is at the very top level.

Where can I go to find more information about this error?  I'm not seeing anything in the error log.

Comment: Like not what type obviously haha. Just what happens.

Comment: You need to look in the 'Problems' view.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open the `Problems` view  (Window->Show View->Problems).

Answer (score 3):

check your build path, some of the mentioned libraries may not be present at the specified locations.

or

refresh the project.

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Show View -> General -> Problems should open up the view which lists all the problems. So you should be able to see the error and its description there.